# Clean way deal with "combinatorics" of simplicial complexes.

Tags: soft-question, simplicial-complex

Whenever I want to verify some simple construction involving chain complexes of simplicial complexes, I get lost in all the alternating signs and stuff.
First verifying that the boundary operator really satisfies $\partial^2 = 0$ requires some work.
Then comes the somewhat confusing definition of chain map, given a simplicial map, which I think looks like:
If $f:X\to Y$ is a simplicial map, and orientations are chosen for $X$ and $Y$, then:
$$
f_* \{x_1,…,x_n\} = \begin{cases} \varepsilon(\sigma)\{f(x_1),…,f(x_n)\} & \text{if $\{f(x_1),…,f(x_n),\}$ has cardinality $n$ and $\sigma$ is the permutation making the orientations match} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$

I'm guaranteed to get lost verifying commutativity of the squares here.

Another example:
You can define another chain complex for $X$ as $C_n$ being formal sums of $n$-tuples of points forming simplices.
Thus you allow degenerate simplices in $C_n$ as well as multiple occurences of a given simplex, but oriented as you please.
This makes functoriality easier to verify since if $f:X\to Y$ is a simplicial map, then $f_n : C_n(X) \to C_n(Y)$ sends a tuple $(x_1,…,x_n)$ to $(fx_1,…,fx_n)$.
But now verifying that the homology you get is the same as the one for the standard construct again involves getting lost in indices.

It seems that the only way to work it all out is to take some A3 sheet of paper, lay down the equality you want to prove, and rewrite as loong as needed, until you get the desired equality.

> **Question**: How do I deal with that?
>   Is there a nice "incremental" construction to do that?

Comment: What if you ask about the parts where you get stuck? Usually, when one learns how to do it, then one gets the intuition and don't need to do every calculation in every case. Otherwise I think this question might be too broad.

Comment: I don't think it's as much with being stuck as being "lost in notation"...
And re broadness, I don't see how the question is too broad; it's about a specific problem and potential specific solutions.
But it might be the problem is really just with me and the solution is to work it out.

Comment: One thing you can do is try first with specific examples so there's no notation, just the actual sums.

Comment: Do you think my problem is mainly with not having enough "experience" to get a good intuition?

Comment: I won't say there is no better notation or better way of defining these things because maybe there is, but usually it is the case that one needs to get a feel of what the equations mean in order not to get lost.

Comment: I’ve found that when working with electrical networks that writing out the boundary and coboundary operators as matrices helps keep things straight.